# How is the Sparkplug is_historical metric property used?

Tags: mqtt

I am reading through the MQTT Sparkplug spec, and I've come across the `is_historical` property of a metric.  The doc explains that it prevents updating of real-time tag values, but I've been unable to find any indication of the use case(s) that led to the inclusion of the property.  Is it perhaps to allow SCADA systems to ignore alarm conditions in historical values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *is_historical* property is used to flag a Metric as a historical value or change event. The most common use case for this would be when an edge application goes offline for a period of time and stores all the data change events locally.  When the application comes back online and publishes the stored values, it can set the is_historical property to let the consuming application know that it is not a live value. The consuming application could then use the *is_historical* property to handle the data appropriately. Your suggestion of ignoring alarm conditions is a good example. The application could also decide to store the event directly in a historical database, bypassing any live displays.